# Segmentation fault with multiple char* comparisons

Tags: c, arrays, char, segmentation-fault, comparison

I have a C program that makes the following comparisons:

```
void compare(char** args) {
    if (find_in_args(args, ">") != -1) {
        printf("In > block");
    }
    else if (find_in_args(args, "<") != -1) {
        printf("In < block");
    }
    else if (find_in_args(args, "|") != -1) {
        printf("In | block");
    }
}
```

where `find_in_args()` iterates through an array of `char*` like so:

```
int find_in_args(char** args, char* target) {
    int found = -1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 10) {
        if (strcmp(args[i], target) != 0)
            ++i;
        else {
            found = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

If `target` happens to be ">", the program outputs `In > block`. If `target` happens to be "<" or "|", the program outputs `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

However, if I move the "<" block to be first, the program will output `In < block` and will give the segmentation fault error if `target` happens to be ">" or "|".

It appears that the comparison that iterates through the `char*` array using `strcmp()` can only happen **once**. I've tried making a copy of `args` for each call of `find_in_args` and performing the comparison on the copy, but the same issue occurs.

Does anyone have an idea of why I can only call the comparison function once, and if so, how to make it so I can call the comparison function n times without getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: could you include code where you allocating args?

Comment: You should print args before starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `i != 10` in the `while` loop. Changing the `while` loop to iterate based on the condition `args[i] != NULL` will fix the issue.

Comment: `args[i] != NULL ` may not fix your issue because if you access `args ` beyond the limit then you will have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, this code section is bound to segfault:

```
while (i != 10) {
    if (strcmp(args[i], target) != 0)
        ++i;
```

You don't specify how you call your function `compare`, but it looks most likely that your `args` is not allocated properly to point to 10 pointers to char. So when you increase `i` in the `while` loop it points to some invalid/illegal location and so the segfault.

Some suggestions:

- Define what `10` is in your program.
- In `compare` and `find_in_args` functions, have an additional parameter to indicate how many pointer to char that `args` is supposed to point to.
- Make sure to allocate/initialise `args` properly